# Maxima or minima of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two polynomials of the same order $n$, say $n=2$, and their coefficients are real numbers, but not zeros. In which case the following function
$$q(x)=\frac{p(x)}{g(x)}$$

has a maximum or a minimum, where $g(x)\neq 0$, and does it matter that they are of the same order? Namely, in this case where the polynomials have the same order, is there any chance that they preserve monotonicity and as a consequence they do not have any optimum value? Is there any theory that covers these topics?

Comment: it seems that $g$ has to be constant if $q = p/g$?

Comment: Well...yes...i was doing some plots in matlab and it seems to be like flat...it increases a little in the beggining but very quickly it converges to some finite point